# react-bootstrap-sweetalert has no styles at all

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

I am having issues rendering a sweet alert. It is showing up for me but with no styles at all, just a white box with a small default button. When I move the mouse over it I see the text in white color but it looks like it has no styles at all.

It is implemented like this:

```
import SweetAlert from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert';
export default function LoginPage() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [alert, setAlert] = React.useState(null);

const warningAlert = () => {
        setAlert(
            <SweetAlert
                warning
                confirmBtnText="Try Again!"
                confirmBtnBsStyle="warning"
                btnSize="lg"
                title="Please Verify your Email and Password!"
                onConfirm={() => hideAlert()}
                onCancel={() => hideAlert()}
            >
                Something went wrong....
            </SweetAlert>
        );
    };
    const hideAlert = () => {
        setAlert(null);
    };

return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            {alert}
            <GridContainer justify="center">
```

It is totally working as intended but just as a white box (ps warning icon is showing fine)

Is there a way to pass custom styles to it? I know that there is a parameter called "style" but I am not sure how to pass styles to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the component as it supports `style` and `customClass` props -

```
 <SweetAlert
    title="Yay!"
    customClass="containerBox" // custom css class
    style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}} // styling can be done here
    confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
    cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
    onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
    onCancel={this.onCancel}
  >
  <span>A custom <span style={{color:'#F8BB86'}}>html</span> message.</span>

 </SweetAlert>
```

Comment: That is the one I was looking for... Thanks!